# $\int_{|z+1|=2}^{}\frac{e^z}{z-2}dz \leq2\pi e$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

This is how I attempted to solve this but I could not get the exact inequality.

$\gamma(t)=1+2e^{it}, t\in [0,2\pi],f(z)=\frac{e^z}{z-2}$

$|e^{1+2it}|=e|e^{2it}|=e.|e^{it}|.|e^{it}|=e$

$|(1+2e^{it})-2|=|2e^{it}-1|\geq ||2e^{it}|-1|=1$

Thus,|$f(\gamma(t))|=\frac{|e^{1+2it}|}{|(1+2e^{it})-2|}\leq e$

Hope someone could hep me out.thanks

Comment: The circle $|z+1|=2$ is centered at $z=-1$ not $z=1$. (Don't know if that's enough to fix things, but you've definitely started off with the wrong $\gamma(t)$.)

Comment: I suppose you haven't yet studied Cauchy integral theorems, have you? Because if you have the integral's value is clearly zero.

Comment: And you have a mistake in your parametrization: the circle's center is $\;-1\;$, **not** $\;1\;$ .

Comment: @Timbuc Nope I have not reached that topic yet just have to show that this inequality holds I just used the ML inequality here

Comment: @Timbuc Ya sorry about that.But that won't change the answer I got right?

Comment: @Timbuc I guess it does sorry but then I get a $1/e$

Comment: @DonaldEdwards, that makes the whole trick. Look at the answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a continuation of Timbuc's answer.

|$\int_{|z+1|=2}^{}\frac{e^z}{z-2}dz| \leq \int_{|z+1|=2}^{}|\frac{e^z}{z-2}|dz=\int_{[0,2\pi]}^{}|\frac{e^{\gamma (t)}}{\gamma(t)-2}|\gamma'(t) dz \leq e \int_{[0,2\pi]}^{}\gamma'(t) dt$=$$e\int_{[0,2\pi]}^{}\ 2ie^{it} dt=0 \leq2\pi e$$

Answer (score 0):

The function 
$$
f(z)=\frac{\mathrm{e}^z}{z-2}
$$
is holomorphic in the disk $D(-1,3)$, and $\{z:\lvert z+1\rvert=2\}\subset D(-1,3)$.

Hence, by virtue of Cauchy's Theorem
$$
\int_{\lvert z+1\rvert=2}\frac{\mathrm{e}^z\,dz}{z-2}=\int_{\lvert z+1\rvert=2}f(z)\,dz=0.
$$

Comment: It seems to be almost obvious the OP hasn't yet studied this, as observed in the comments.

Comment: Can you check if my answer is correct?

Answer (score 0):

The parametrization of $\;|z+1|=2\;$ is

$$\gamma(t)=-1+2e^{it}\;,\;\;t\in[0,2\pi]\;,\;\;\gamma'(t)=2ie^{it}\implies |\gamma'(t)|=2$$

and also

$$e^{-1+2e^{it}}\implies |e^z|=\left|e^{-1+2\cos t+2i\sin t}\right|=e^{2\cos t-1}$$

so that finally

$$\left|\oint\limits_\gamma \frac{e^z}{z-2}dz\right|\le\oint\limits_\gamma\frac{|e^z|}{|z-2|}dz\le \frac{e^{2\cos t-1}}{5}\cdot 4\pi$$

and then we must prove that

$$\frac{e^{2\cos t-1}}{5}\cdot 4\pi\le 2\pi e\iff e^{2\cos t-1}\le\frac52e\;\;(**)$$

But if we denote

$$f(t):=e^{2\cos t-1}\implies f'(t)=-2\sin t\,e^{2\cos t-1}$$

so that the function is monotone decreasing on $\;(0,\pi)\;$ and monotone increasing on $\;(\pi, 2\pi)\;$, and thus the maximal values are obtained when

$$t=0\implies \;\;\;f(0)=e^1=e\\
t=2\pi\implies f(2\pi)=e^1=e$$

and thus we get that anyway (**) is true.

Comment: Thanks but how did you arrive at the final inequality $\frac{4\pi}e<2\pi e$?

Comment: It is NOT true that $e^z=e^{-1+2it}$, when $z=-1+2e^{it}$.

Comment: Well @DonaldEdwards: $$2<e<3\implies e^2>2=\frac{4\pi}{2\pi}$$

Comment: I think it is as we're on the circle $\;|z+1|=2\;$, @YiorgosS.Smyrlis : it is just substitution of the parametrization, isn't it?

Comment: In fact what we have is: $\lvert e^z\rvert=\lvert e^{-1+2e^{it}}\rvert=e^{2\cos t-1}$.

Comment: I think I see your point, @YiorgosS.Smyrlis and you're right: I forgot the exponential as I tried to follow the OP's comment to address. Thanks, I shall edit my answer shortly.

Comment: @DonaldEdwards, please do check the editing of my answer, which has to be done thanks to Yiorgos comment above.

Comment: Hmmm...I'm not sure whether that $\;5\;$ in the denominator is correct. It is the maximum for $\;|z-2|\;$ when $\;z\in\gamma\;$, though...but it should have been *the minimum* for the fraction to be greater. Shall think of this a little more.

Comment: @Timbuc It should be 1 instead of 5. This leads to a problem in the iff statement of yours I suppose

Comment: @Timbuc Are you sure this is right?

Comment: What is "this", @Heisenberg ? As for my answer I already wrote my doubts about it. I shall either find a way to correct the estimmation or esle delete my answer. Did you mean something else?

Comment: @Timbuc Your methods are correct however it seems to me that the desired inequality cannot be derived this way

Comment: @Timbuc And as you have mention it should the minimum of |z-2| so the minimum should be 1

Comment: Yes, @Heisenberg: I know, as it was already mentioned in the comments.

Comment: @Timbuc Check my continuation for your answer I hope that it is correct