# A question on absolute values of line integrals

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

Let $f:U\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be continuous and $\gamma:[a,b]\rightarrow U$ be a smooth path where $U$ is open. Then we know that $$\int_{\gamma}^{}\ f(z)dz=\int_{\gamma}^{}\ f(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)dt$$
What I need to know is whether the following is correct. Can we write that $$|{ \int_{\gamma}^{}\ f(z)dz}| \leq \int_{\gamma}^{}\ |f(z)|dz=\int_{[a.b]}^{}\ |f(\gamma(t))|\gamma'(t)dt$$
I just need a small verification Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, $dz$, equivalently $\gamma'(t)$, is not real-valued, so

$$\int_\gamma \lvert f(z)\rvert\,dz = \int_a^b \lvert f(\gamma(t))\rvert\gamma'(t)\,dt$$

need not be real. Then the inequality doesn't make sense. What is true is

$$\left\lvert \int_\gamma f(z)\,dz\right\rvert \leqslant \int_\gamma \lvert f(z)\rvert\, \lvert dz\rvert = \int_a^b \lvert f(\gamma(t))\rvert\,\lvert \gamma'(t)\rvert\,dt.$$

Comment: Thanks. Although it may not be true in general can it be true for specific cases?. If you have time please be kind enough to take a look at the answer I gave in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/973385/int-z1-2-fracezz-2dz-leq2-pi-e/980909#980909 this.

Comment: Well, it's always true if $\gamma'(t) \geqslant 0$ for all $t\in [a,b]$, or for $f \equiv 0$. One can construct other cases where the inequality makes sense since both sides are real, and one can get examples where the inequality holds and others where it's wrong (e.g. $\gamma'(t) < 0$ for all $t$ makes it wrong unless $f\equiv 0$ on the trace of $\gamma$). But those examples aren't particularly interesting. I'm looking at it now.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification hoping for a feedback on the link I shared thanks for looking into it

Comment: Unfortunately, since $\gamma'(t)$ is not real and non-negative, you can't argue $$\int_{[0,2\pi]} \left\lvert \frac{e^{\gamma(t)}}{\gamma(t)-2}\right\rvert \gamma'(t)\,dt \leqslant e\int_{[0,2\pi]} \gamma'(t)\,dt$$ because $\left\lvert \frac{e^{\gamma(t)}}{\gamma(t)-2}\right\rvert \leqslant e$. That argument requires non-negativity. And since $\left\lvert \frac{e^{\gamma(t)}}{\gamma(t)-2}\right\rvert$ isn't constant, we probably have $$\int_{[0,2\pi]} \left\lvert \frac{e^{\gamma(t)}}{\gamma(t)-2}\right\rvert \gamma'(t)\,dt \neq 0.$$ If you use $\lvert \gamma'(t)\rvert$, you get a too large

Comment: bound ($4\pi e$) if you do the simple estimate. Without appealing to Cauchy's theorem(s), I don't think you can do it in a very simple way. (Timbuc's answer may or may not be correct, haven't had the time to check that yet.)

Comment: After finding the upper bound e the ML inequality can be used to get $4\pi e$

Comment: Anyway thanks alot for looking into it